# Storing the result of an observable into variable

Tags: angular

I have written a service that returns an observable. I need to initialise the data variable in the service method how do i do it

```
 private data: any;

   public getOutstandingAgreements(userAgreementId?: number): Observable<AgreementsModel[]> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (userAgreementId) {
      params = params.set('userAgreementId', userAgreementId.toString());
  }

   if (this.data) {
    return this.data;
  }
   return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params});

  }
```

I tried the following but it did not work

```
 public getOutstandingAgreements(userAgreementId?: number): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (userAgreementId) {
      params = params.set('userAgreementId', userAgreementId.toString());
  }

   if (this.data) {
    return this.data;
  }
   return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params})
                                                                .pipe(map((x) => {this.data = x; }));

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tap:

```
return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params})
    .pipe(tap((x) => {this.data = x; }));
```

and you need to keep your api consistent so use `of` to return your saved data:

```
if (this.data) {
  return of(this.data);
}
```

this transforms it into an observable, though there are arguably better ways to cache observable responses, such as with the `shareReplay` operator:

```
private data$: Observable<AgreementsModel[]>;

public getOutstandingAgreements(userAgreementId?: number): Observable<AgreementsModel[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  if (userAgreementId) {
      params = params.set('userAgreementId', userAgreementId.toString());
  }

  if (!this.data$) {
    this.data$ = this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params}).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
  return this.data$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params})
  .pipe(tap((x) => {this.data = x; }));
```

The variable setting doesn't get called until you subscribe to it though.

```
this.getOutstandingAgreements(...).subscribe()
```

With this usecase, maybe a Promise would work better?

Comment: The first time it return the data fine to the subscribe. The second time it hits the if block logic that is checking if data exist and fails with error this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(...).subscribe is not a function . I have also added return x as suggested by other person who has answered

Answer (score 0):

try add an `return x;` in you .map function.
Try this:

```
return this.http.get<AgreementsModel[]>(`${this.baseUrl}outstanding-agreements`, {params})
  .pipe(tap((x) => {this.data = x; return x; }));
```

Comment: The first time it return the data fine to the subscribe. The second time it hits the if block logic that is checking if data exist and fails with error  this.agreementsService.getOutstandingAgreements(...).subscribe is not a function

Comment: it is becouse the second time, you return to `data`, not observable. 
Why don't you try to treat to `data` like a BehaviorSubject and subscribe to the function's response place?